# Are there step by step instructions for installing orbeon forms in heroku?

Tags: orbeon

Is there a step by step guide for installing orbeon forms in Heroku?  I am tyring to figure out what I need to do, to get orbeon forms up and running in heroku.

Comment: JGPK, did you get a chance to check Heroku's doc mentioned in my answer below? Did that help? ‑Alex

Answer (score 0):

Orbeon Forms comes as a `war` file that you can deploy on Tomcat (or other servlet container / Java application server). So I'd recommend you check Heroku's own documentation on [Deploying Tomcat-based Java Web Applications with Webapp Runner](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner), and wherever it mentions a `war` file, use Orbeon Forms' `war` file.